# Trying to get the next value in sequence from a postgres DB, with django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have a sequence defined in my database that I want to use in my django application.  I assumed I could use the raw sql method specified in the django documentation here:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/sql/.  My plan was to execute the following SQL statment:

```
select nextval('winner')
```

where winner is the sequence I want to get the next value from.  Here is my code:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction

.....

cursor = connection.cursor()

result = cursor.execute("select nextval('winner')")
```

The result is always a NoneType object.  This seems pretty simple and straightforward, but I haven't been able to make this work.  I've tried it in the interactive console with the same results.  If I look in the connection.queries object, i see this:

```
{'time': '0.000', 'sql': "select nextval('winner')"}
```

The sql generated is valid.  Any ideas?

I'm using:

- Django 1.1
- Python 2.6
- Postgres 8.3
- Psycopg2
- Mac OSX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cursor.execute` *always* returns None.

To get the value from the SQL statement, you have to use `cursor.fetchone()` (or `fetchall()`).

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), although note that this doesn't actually have anything to do with Django, but is the standard Python SQL DB API.

Answer (score 11):

This code will work:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select nextval('winner')")
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

[full documentation about cursor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)